# jQuery mouse enter/leave not correctly detecting hovering area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I looked around what I would like to achieve, but I wasn't able to find any suitable answer.

Basically I can't make the code to correctly detect mouse entering and leaving a div that is overlapping another div.
This is my current situation:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2f5xx73y/

HTML:

```
<div style='height: 100%; width: 100%;padding: 30%;'>
   <div class='box'>
       <div class='inner-box'>Merry xmas!</div>
   </div>
   <div class='box'>
       <div class='inner-box'>Happy new year!</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
.inner-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.zoomed-inner-box {
    height: 160%;
    width: 160%;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".inner-box").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).attr("class", "zoomed-inner-box");
});

$(".inner-box").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).attr("class", "inner-box");
});
```

As you can see there are two boxes which become bigger when hovered overlapping the other box. 
Going right to left everything works fine, in fact the red div goes away as soon as the mouse leave it. This doesn't happen in the opposite direction, where a mouseleave event it's fired as soon as the cursor enters the green div behind the red one, while I want the red div to go away when the mouse completely leave it.

I also tried using the `:hover` selector for the `inner-box` class but it has the exact same behaviour. Do you know a nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `z-index` on `.zommed-inner-box` to overwrite the `.inner-box`'s `z-index`. That way the currently hovered box has a higher z-index than `.inner-box` :

```
.inner-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1; <---- original z-index
}

.zoomed-inner-box {
  height: 160%;
  width: 160%;
  top: -30%;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2; <---- higher z-index
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2f5xx73y/1/)